# some criteria peg CPU using Scripting Bridge and NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa, itunes, nspredicate, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to get a list of tracks out of iTunes via Scripting Bridge. I'm using `NSPredicate` because that's [the recommended way](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-SW12). This works very well in some cases, and is unusably slow in others. For instance, this will execute very quickly:

```
NSString *formatString = @"artist == ABC AND album == XYZ";
NSPredicate *trackFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formatString];
NSArray *tracksToPlay = [[libraryPlaylist fileTracks] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:trackFilter];
```

(`libraryPlaylist` is an iTunesLibraryPlaylist object that was created elsewhere.)

But if I add either `kind` or `videoKind` to the mix, iTunes hits 100% CPU for a minute or more.

```
NSString *formatString = @"artist == ABC AND album == XYZ AND kind != 'PDF document' AND videoKind == %@", ;
NSPredicate *trackFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formatString, [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithTypeCode:iTunesEVdKNone]];
NSArray *tracksToPlay = [[libraryPlaylist fileTracks] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:trackFilter];
```

But that will eventually work. The real failure is `albumArtist`. If I try

```
NSString *formatString = @"albumArtist == ABC AND album == XYZ";
NSPredicate *trackFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formatString];
NSArray *tracksToPlay = [[libraryPlaylist fileTracks] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:trackFilter];
```

iTunes will go to 100% CPU and sit there for I don't know how long. (I gave up after 3 or 4 minutes.) Am I missing something or is this a bug in iTunes?

#### Additional info

My code takes the resulting tracks and calls another method to add them to a playlist (also using Scripting Bridge). I noticed when trying to filter by kind, the tracks would slowly pop onto the list one by one while iTunes hammered the CPU. This can only mean that `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` has already returned its results, so what is iTunes working so hard on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416285/itunes-scripting-bridge-reveal-does-not-work) indirectly helped me find the answer.

Using the “Library” playlist causes a number of unusual problems. Using the “Music” playlist instead seems to fix them. In the example above, setting `libraryPlaylist` this way is what caused the problem:

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
iTunesSource *library = [[[[iTunes sources] get] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %i", iTunesESrcLibrary]] objectAtIndex:0];
iTunesLibraryPlaylist *libraryPlaylist = [[[library libraryPlaylists] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Getting the "Music" playlist instead of the "Library" playlist is the answer:

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
iTunesSource *library = [[[[iTunes sources] get] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %i", iTunesESrcLibrary]] objectAtIndex:0];
iTunesLibraryPlaylist *libraryPlaylist = [[[[library playlists] get] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"specialKind == %i", iTunesESpKMusic]] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Other things to be aware of

The `"albumArtist == ABC AND album == XYZ"` filter in the original question was actually running pretty quickly. What's slow is anything you do with the result afterward. Calling `get` right away is a partial solution. (`get` runs as slow as anything else, but by doing it up front, you limit the slowness to a single operation. Also note that `get` only works on an `SBElementArray`.)

I've also found that calling `fileTracks` re-introduces some slowness. Using `tracks` instead fixes that. So the filter should read:

```
NSArray *tracksToPlay = [(SBElementArray *)[[libraryPlaylist tracks] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:trackFilter] get];
```

(When using "Library", only `fileTracks` would return objects with a `location` property, which you need to add them to a playlist. After switching to "Music", `tracks` seems to return objects with a location as well.)